# Como “limitar” um JComboBox de acordo com o item selecionado?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Tenho um `JComboBox`, e eu limito o tamanho dele, com o seguinte código:

```
jcb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 21));
```

Porém gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de, depois que eu escolher uma opção, o conteúdo ficasse exibido completamente. O que acontece é que, como eu defini um tamanho menor que o conteúdo, ele esconde o que for maior (o conteúdo que for maior que o combo).

Segue imagem para ilustrar a situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma "ilustração pra ajudar"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que não definir um tamanho maior? Redimensiona-lo dinamicamente implicaria em reconstruir a tela inteira a cada redimensionamento.

Comment: Porque o usuário pode digitar um "conteúdo" muito grande, então se o conteúdo for muito grande, o combo vai ficar enorme.

Comment: Mas se voce redimensionar conforme o tamanho, ele vai ficar enorme de qualquer jeito.

Comment: Então, a minha dúvida, é saber se não há uma maneira de não modificar esse tamanho, e quando for selecionar o item, ele mostre só o conteúdo completo, enquanto o usuário estiver escolhendo, depois ele pode continuar do tamanho que eu defini (pequeno = 100/21).

Comment: Sinceramente sua duvida está meio confusa, o que você explicou agora é diferente do que está na pergunta.

Comment: Gustavo, com o que apresentou adicionalmente minha resposta estava fora do que queria, por isso retirei.

Comment: @Leo tudo bem. Agradeço por ter tentado meu ajudar!

Comment: Encontrei uma solução que redimensiona o pop up do combo, mas o combo não redimensiona se a opção for maior que ele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há um classe chamada [**`BoundsPopupMenuListener`**](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/), que pode controlar o tamanho do popup que se abre das opções do combo, de acordo com o item de maior tamanho.

Após umas adaptações, consegui fazer com que, ao se alterar um item no combo, ele fosse redimensionado ao tamanho do item.

Basta adicionar a classe `BoundsPopupMenuListener` no seu projeto e configurá-la como um listener de popup do combo, conforme segue no exemplo executável abaixo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboResizing {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Frame Teste");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        String[] tabs = {"txt short", "text more longer", "text more more longer"};

        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(tabs);

        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //este método redefine o tamanho preferido
                //do combo baseado num valor prototipo
                //passado como parametro, neste caso
                //o item selecionado
                combo.setPrototypeDisplayValue(combo.getSelectedItem());
                //força o frame a ser redesenhado               
                frame.pack();
            }
        });

        //classe que define o tamanho do popup do combo
        //conforme o tamanho do valor prototipo
        //e redimensiona se houver itens muito grande
        BoundsPopupMenuListener listener = new BoundsPopupMenuListener(true, false);
        combo.addPopupMenuListener(listener);
        combo.setPrototypeDisplayValue(combo.getSelectedItem());

        frame.add(combo);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ComboResizing().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Os trechos relevantes são os que possuem comentários explicativos.

O resultado desse exemplo ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da classe `BoundsPopupMenuListener` está disponível no link no fim da resposta, mas vou copiá-lo aqui para facilitar a consulta, caso o link fique indisponivel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

/**
 * This class will change the bounds of the JComboBox popup menu to support
 * different functionality. It will support the following features: - a
 * horizontal scrollbar can be displayed when necessary - the popup can be wider
 * than the combo box - the popup can be displayed above the combo box
 *
 * Class will only work for a JComboBox that uses a BasicComboPop.
 */
public class BoundsPopupMenuListener implements PopupMenuListener {

    private boolean scrollBarRequired = true;
    private boolean popupWider;
    private int maximumWidth = -1;
    private boolean popupAbove;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    /**
     * Convenience constructore to allow the display of a horizontal scrollbar
     * when required.
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener() {
        this(true, false, -1, false);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience constructor that allows you to display the popup wider and/or
     * above the combo box.
     *
     * @param popupWider when true, popup width is based on the popup preferred
     * width
     * @param popupAbove when true, popup is displayed above the combobox
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener(boolean popupWider, boolean popupAbove) {
        this(true, popupWider, -1, popupAbove);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience constructor that allows you to display the popup wider than
     * the combo box and to specify the maximum width
     *
     * @param maximumWidth the maximum width of the popup. The popupAbove value
     * is set to "true".
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener(int maximumWidth) {
        this(true, true, maximumWidth, false);
    }

    /**
     * General purpose constructor to set all popup properties at once.
     *
     * @param scrollBarRequired display a horizontal scrollbar when the
     * preferred width of popup is greater than width of scrollPane.
     * @param popupWider display the popup at its preferred with
     * @param maximumWidth limit the popup width to the value specified (minimum
     * size will be the width of the combo box)
     * @param popupAbove display the popup above the combo box
     *
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener(
            boolean scrollBarRequired, boolean popupWider, int maximumWidth, boolean popupAbove) {
        setScrollBarRequired(scrollBarRequired);
        setPopupWider(popupWider);
        setMaximumWidth(maximumWidth);
        setPopupAbove(popupAbove);
    }

    /**
     * Return the maximum width of the popup.
     *
     * @return the maximumWidth value
     */
    public int getMaximumWidth() {
        return maximumWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Set the maximum width for the popup. This value is only used when
     * setPopupWider( true ) has been specified. A value of -1 indicates that
     * there is no maximum.
     *
     * @param maximumWidth the maximum width of the popup
     */
    public void setMaximumWidth(int maximumWidth) {
        this.maximumWidth = maximumWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the popup should be displayed above the combo box.
     *
     * @return the popupAbove value
     */
    public boolean isPopupAbove() {
        return popupAbove;
    }

    /**
     * Change the location of the popup relative to the combo box.
     *
     * @param popupAbove true display popup above the combo box, false display
     * popup below the combo box.
     */
    public void setPopupAbove(boolean popupAbove) {
        this.popupAbove = popupAbove;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the popup might be displayed wider than the combo box
     *
     * @return the popupWider value
     */
    public boolean isPopupWider() {
        return popupWider;
    }

    /**
     * Change the width of the popup to be the greater of the width of the combo
     * box or the preferred width of the popup. Normally the popup width is
     * always the same size as the combo box width.
     *
     * @param popupWider true adjust the width as required.
     */
    public void setPopupWider(boolean popupWider) {
        this.popupWider = popupWider;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the horizontal scroll bar might be required for the popup
     *
     * @return the scrollBarRequired value
     */
    public boolean isScrollBarRequired() {
        return scrollBarRequired;
    }

    /**
     * For some reason the default implementation of the popup removes the
     * horizontal scrollBar from the popup scroll pane which can result in the
     * truncation of the rendered items in the popop. Adding a scrollBar back to
     * the scrollPane will allow horizontal scrolling if necessary.
     *
     * @param scrollBarRequired true add horizontal scrollBar to scrollPane
     * false remove the horizontal scrollBar
     */
    public void setScrollBarRequired(boolean scrollBarRequired) {
        this.scrollBarRequired = scrollBarRequired;
    }

    /**
     * Alter the bounds of the popup just before it is made visible.
     */
    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

        if (comboBox.getItemCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final Object child = comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);

        if (child instanceof BasicComboPopup) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    customizePopup((BasicComboPopup) child);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected void customizePopup(BasicComboPopup popup) {
        scrollPane = getScrollPane(popup);

        if (popupWider) {
            popupWider(popup);
        }

        checkHorizontalScrollBar(popup);

        //  For some reason in JDK7 the popup will not display at its preferred
        //  width unless its location has been changed from its default
        //  (ie. for normal "pop down" shift the popup and reset)
        Component comboBox = popup.getInvoker();
        Point location = comboBox.getLocationOnScreen();

        if (popupAbove) {
            int height = popup.getPreferredSize().height;
            popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y - height);
        } else {
            int height = comboBox.getPreferredSize().height;
            popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y + height - 1);
            popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y + height);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Adjust the width of the scrollpane used by the popup
     */
    protected void popupWider(BasicComboPopup popup) {
        JList list = popup.getList();

        //  Determine the maximimum width to use:
        //  a) determine the popup preferred width
        //  b) limit width to the maximum if specified
        //  c) ensure width is not less than the scroll pane width
        int popupWidth = list.getPreferredSize().width
                + 5 // make sure horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear
                + getScrollBarWidth(popup, scrollPane);

        if (maximumWidth != -1) {
            popupWidth = Math.min(popupWidth, maximumWidth);
        }

        Dimension scrollPaneSize = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
        popupWidth = Math.max(popupWidth, scrollPaneSize.width);

        //  Adjust the width
        scrollPaneSize.width = popupWidth;
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(scrollPaneSize);
        scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPaneSize);
    }

    /*
     *  This method is called every time:
     *  - to make sure the viewport is returned to its default position
     *  - to remove the horizontal scrollbar when it is not wanted
     */
    private void checkHorizontalScrollBar(BasicComboPopup popup) {
        //  Reset the viewport to the left

        JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
        Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
        p.x = 0;
        viewport.setViewPosition(p);

        //  Remove the scrollbar so it is never painted
        if (!scrollBarRequired) {
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
            return;
        }

        //  Make sure a horizontal scrollbar exists in the scrollpane
        JScrollBar horizontal = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();

        if (horizontal == null) {
            horizontal = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(horizontal);
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        }

        //  Potentially increase height of scroll pane to display the scrollbar
        if (horizontalScrollBarWillBeVisible(popup, scrollPane)) {
            Dimension scrollPaneSize = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
            scrollPaneSize.height += horizontal.getPreferredSize().height;
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(scrollPaneSize);
            scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPaneSize);
            scrollPane.revalidate();
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Get the scroll pane used by the popup so its bounds can be adjusted
     */
    protected JScrollPane getScrollPane(BasicComboPopup popup) {
        JList list = popup.getList();
        Container c = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, list);

        return (JScrollPane) c;
    }

    /*
     *  I can't find any property on the scrollBar to determine if it will be
     *  displayed or not so use brute force to determine this.
     */
    protected int getScrollBarWidth(BasicComboPopup popup, JScrollPane scrollPane) {
        int scrollBarWidth = 0;
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) popup.getInvoker();

        if (comboBox.getItemCount() > comboBox.getMaximumRowCount()) {
            JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            scrollBarWidth = vertical.getPreferredSize().width;
        }

        return scrollBarWidth;
    }

    /*
     *  I can't find any property on the scrollBar to determine if it will be
     *  displayed or not so use brute force to determine this.
     */
    protected boolean horizontalScrollBarWillBeVisible(BasicComboPopup popup, JScrollPane scrollPane) {
        JList list = popup.getList();
        int scrollBarWidth = getScrollBarWidth(popup, scrollPane);
        int popupWidth = list.getPreferredSize().width + scrollBarWidth;

        return popupWidth > scrollPane.getPreferredSize().width;
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        //  In its normal state the scrollpane does not have a scrollbar

        if (scrollPane != null) {
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Referências:

[Combo Box Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679421/why-jcombobox-ignore-prototypedisplayvalue)

[Why JComboBox ignore PrototypeDisplayValue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8679421/5524514)

Comment: Opa, se encaixou muito bem para o que eu precisava. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @GustavoSantos só tome cuidado com itens muito extensos. Senão vai cair no problema que comentamos na pergunta, estou vendo um jeito aqui de limitar o maximo do combo, caso o tamanho fique longo, dê uma conferida na resposta depois pra ver se houve edição com esse recurso.

Comment: ok, e mais uma vez, obrigado!